# Orthogonal Grassmanians: cases where $\text{OG}( \mathbb{P}^1 , Q) \not \simeq \mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, galois-cohomology, grassmannians, conic-sections

Let $Q = \{ q(x_0, \dots, x_4) = 0  \}$ be a quadric-threefold over a field $k$. Are there cases where the orthogonal Grassmanian $\text{OG}( \mathbb{P}^1 , Q)$ is not a copy of $\mathbb{P}^3$?

Here's a Lemma ([Kollar](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01276)) that says it is a $\mathbb{P}^3$ iff it contains a line:

> Lemma 61
>
> (1) $\text{OG}(\mathbb{P}^1,Q)$ is a [Severi-Brauer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Severi%E2%80%93Brauer_variety) variety
>
> (3) $\text{OG}(\mathbb{P}^1,Q) \simeq \mathbb{P}^3 \longleftrightarrow \text{OG}(\mathbb{P}^1,Q) \text{ contains a line }\longleftrightarrow q \sim y_0y_1 + y_2y_3 + a y_4^2$

but isn't this variety the Grassmanian of *lines*?

Here I believe $\simeq$ means "isomorphism of varieties" (instead of birational equivalence $\stackrel{bir}{\sim}$) and the symbol $\sim$ is "rational equivalence of quadratic forms".

---

I am still parsing the definition based on the comments I am wondering:

- Are there other 3-dimensional Severi-Brauer varieties over $\mathbb{Q}$ other than $\{ 0\}$ and $\mathbb{P}^3$ ?
  I believe the answer is *no* because quadric sections themselves are varieties of this type.

However Wikipedia says this:

> In mathematics, a Severi–Brauer variety over a field K is an algebraic variety V which becomes isomorphic to a projective space over an algebraic closure of K.
>
> In dimension one, the Severi–Brauer varieties are conics. The corresponding central simple algebras are the quaternion algebras. The algebra $(a,b)_K$ corresponds to the conic C(a,b) with equation
>   $$ C(a,b) = \big\{ z^{2} -ax^{2}-by^{2} = 0 \big\} $$
>   and the algebra $(a,b)_K$ splits, that is, $(a,b)_K$ is isomorphic to a matrix algebra over $K$, if and only if $C(a,b)$ has a point defined over $K$: this is in turn equivalent to $C(a,b)$ being isomorphic to the projective line over $K$.

So we get that [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) play a role in SB varieties and that conics (and one could imagine quadrics) are Severi-Brauer varieties. 
 Now I am confused again, that if the conic has a single point over $K$, then it is a projective line $\mathbb{P}^1(K)$.

Does this correspond to the trivial element of the [Brauer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group)?  There are even expositions of Severi-Brauer varieties that are more [geometric](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04368) and avoid the use of Galois cohomology.

---

In Neukirch's Cohomology of Number Fields, they give a defintion of the Brauer Group:

> The Brauer group of a field $K$ is the set of similarity classes $[A]$ of central $K$-simple algebras $A$ endowed with the multiplication
>   $$[A][B] = [A \otimes_K B] $$
>   Two central simple $K$-algebras $A$ and $B$ are similar if 
>   $$ A \otimes_K M_r(K) \simeq B \otimes_K M_s(K) $$
>   for some $r,s$.  (Chapter 6.3)

The group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ keeps being mentions in regards to various exact sequences and the Hasse principle. It seems the challenge is to stay grounded and not to float away with these definitions, for what is a very concrete object.

Comment: The quadric $Q$ in (3) is rational, so any non-rational quadric will do, e.g.
 $q=x_1^2+\cdots +x_4^2$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @abx the variety you're describing is empty over $\mathbb{R}$ is that the only other possibility? We can't have Severi-Brauer varieties over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Of course we can, take the same quadric over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: Come on! The Brauer group of $\Bbb{Q}$ is huge, and each nonzero element is represented by a nontrivial Severi–Brauer variety. I suggest that you look at a good book on the subject rather than asking this kind of questions here.

Comment: The conic $x^2+y^2+z^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. *Central Simple Algebras and Galois Cohomology* by Gille and Szamuely (Cambridge).